# Keeping a single quotation mark in regular expression ignored

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm not really sure why my regex is being ignored sometimes. I say sometimes because when testing it with other sentences such as "Don't don't i'll" it seems to keep the single quote mark as wanted.

```
def alternate_words(words)
  words.split.map {|x| x.gsub(/[^\‘0-9A-Za-z]/, "")}
             .delete_if {|x| x == ""}
             .select.with_index {|x, i| i.even?}
end

alternate_words("Would a test upon . . . ? I hope not. But even if it is, don’t let that mail if you ! ?")
#=> ["Would", "test", "I", "not", "even", "it", "dont"]
```

However this is a test sentence so its unable to pass because it keeps returning "dont" instead of "don't"

Comment: You have a curly apostrophe in the `don’t`, add `’` to the regex: `/[^‘’0-9A-Za-z]/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you need both curly and straight apostrophes in your regexp:

```
x.gsub(/[^\‘\’'0-9A-Za-z]/, "")
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked.

My goodness I didn't realise that there were two versions of apostrophes, that really threw me off.